Manual Auto Focus in Flutter Camera
I'm working on a custom camera application using the Flutter camera plugin. I want to keep auto-focus off by default and implement a slider to manually set the auto-focus range.
I've provided a video link below showing what I want to achieve.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWu2Ahp-Nys&list=PL8J9oi-nz2_VHRNXrxL417K7KK_dEd9WD
